# Can't find Hello World app in genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

Hello i can run Genymotion emulator without any problems.
So when i am on homescreen i click list of apps (this [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkHzz.png))
and the app is just not there...
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0DV1.png)

## What i tried {{START}}

1. I tried to enable "ADB Integration" in Android Studio
   **Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration** when i did this
   the emulator said gave me an error which said
   **Process system isn't responding**
   **Do want to close it?**
   **Wait** **Ok**
   I would post image but i need 10 reputation to have 2+ links...
2. Rebuilding Project

## What i tried {{END}}

I don't have any ideas..
This was my first question sorry for mistakes.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you run your project?

Comment: by running project do you mean clicking the red button (genymotion plugin)? if no then i didn't